# Why do Node.JS packages have to be compiled with Electron to be able to use them in VSCode extension development?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We have a VSCode extension that uses node, but when I import it directly, it doesn't work because it has to be compiled using the Electron framework.
When I compile the module with Electron, I have no issues.

What is the difference? What does the Electron framework do?

Thanks,
Akhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron ships its [own, custom version of node](https://github.com/electron/node) and VS Code uses that to run extensions. The difference between Electron's node version and your node install doesn't matter much when executing JavaScript but native node modules [must be recompiled](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules) to ensure they are built for the specific version of node electron uses.

This [document on ABI stability in node](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/abi-stability/) covers some of the reasons why recompiling for different node versions is required in the first place